# Labels in ArcGIS Pro overlap although there is enough space

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling

I have two separate label classes which I want to display in my map without overlapping. There is enough space to place the labels under each other but ArcGIS Pro still places them overlapping. I already assigned the highest possible feature weight and a Label buffer of 15% to both classes but this did not help.

I don't want to convert the labels to annotations because it's a dynamic dataset.

Any tips on that?

[image]
[image]

EDIT: These are my current Labeleling properties for all classes:

[image: Screenshot Labeling properties 1]
[image: Screenshot Labeling properties 2]

Comment: depends on how flexible you want the labelling to be.  But you could configure them both to appear below the point, but at a fixed distance from the point, and a different fixed difference for each label class.  If you cannot do it with 2 classes in one layer, then add a duplicate layer with different labelling properties (ie, effectively the second labelling class).

Comment: I added two screenshots with my current settings.

Comment: I tried the approch with the fixed distance but for some reason the distances still vary and ArcGIS seems to ignore the distance values I enter. Could it be that some other settings overrule this?

Comment: Turn off Background labels (may help) and Never remove (will definitely help). I have never encountered a reason to select Never remove.

Comment: I solved this issue by using fixed distances. Turning off "Never remove" lead to cases where labels were not displayed if I had many other labels nearby.